# Is it wise to sign such agreement that will allow company to extract all information about you prior or current work?

Tags: salary, job-offer, recruitment, negotiation, employment-agreement

I heard one of my close one has passed two phone interview and now getting ready for a face-to-face interview. However, they now sent him the applicant application to fill out that has a clause in the agreement to sign shows:

> I authorize all individuals, schools, and firms named therein, except my current employer if so noted, to provide any information requested about me and I release them from all liability for damage in providing this information.

Potentially, I think it includes his current pay. He feels that just does not make sense to reveal that (not to mention, the form itself ask for pay rate of current and previous job).

He repeated mentioned it to the recruiter he felt not comfortable to reveal current pay rate he has, but seems the company wants to push it.

What should he do? Should he sign it? Does it means the company is not really the one who will respect the individual's value by trying to low ball him repeatedly?

Comment: Your friend REALLY needs to have a lawyer go over the contract _before_ he signs it and explain the implications of such a contract.  Voting to close as legal advice.

Comment: @JaneS Its not a contract, but an application agreement (you konw, something you fillup when you apply a job anywhere?), because he told them his expected salary, but they have not yet respond on it, but instead, this application came up after all those interviews

Comment: A signed agreement is not a contact?

Comment: Ultimately, if the company is unwilling to offer the salary he is after, does it really matter whether that is because they know his current salary? You say that he has told them his expected salary. Either they're willing to pay that to acquire his services, or they're not.

Comment: I very much doubt that such a document would release them from responsibility of breaking the law.

Comment: No one is going to see a lawyer and pay hundreds of dollars to get pointless advice about a boilerplate "contract" for a job that might not materialize anyway. The potential employer just wants to know salary history and educational credentials. If you give it to them and they low-ball, you can always walk away.The real question is what real harm can come from giving such permission to a potential employer?

Comment: @teego1967 basically, the low ball aspect of it

Comment: @Chen, if your salary expectation is in-line with market rate and your previous salary was below market rate-- you have some room for negotiation. You're more likely to get a positive outcome by negotiating a higher-offer than refusing to sign the agreement (which may "close the door" immediately).

Comment: You forgot to mention the country you're in.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common form that you will have to fill out a lot. It gives them the right to investigate you since that's not something that can be done legally without you giving them permission. They can only use this information for the purposes of determining if they want to hire you, they cannot use this information for any other purposes. It's really up to you if you'd like to sign this document, but do remember that failure to give this kind of permission might result in them disqualifying you from employment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the document is a contract. It is the applicant giving other entities, besides the current employer, a release from liability if they answer the questions requested by the potential employer.

Note that it doesn't require them to answer the questions.

Many companies will only provide the minimum amount of info: dates of employment, and job title. They will only provide salary information if the request is coming from a bank for a loan, or if you have explicitly requested them to provide it.

The form is not unusual. If they are uncomfortable with it, they should move on to other places to apply. Over time they may realize how common it is, and accept it; or they will find an exception.

While having a potential employer knowing what you made with a previous company may seem like a bad thing it doesn't force you into accepting a job that pay less then you need. Also remember knowing what I made 5 years ago tells them nothing about what I would accept to join a new company.

Comment: Well, I guess in this case it does matter, because his request the company of a salary that is 90% higher than current one. Almost double